# How to exit a vim function from python code?

Tags: python, function, vim, return, exit

Example:

```
function! MyFunc()
   do this
   do that

python3 << endpython
if var = "something":
   return
else:
   do this
endpython

endfunction
```

The `return` command doesn't work:
E880: Can't handle SystemExit of python exception in vim

Same when I use `exit()` or `quit()`

How can I exit the vim function from within python code?

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
function! MyFunc()
....

python << EOF

if ...:
   result=0
else:
   ...
   result=1

vim.command("let pyResult=%d"%result)
EOF

if pyResult == 0
   return
else
   ..........
endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Hi Kent! Thank you for answer. I know your solution but it doesn't stop executing the rest of my python code (after the if/else statement).

Comment: @Reman I think you can re-design/construct your python codes to make it happen.

Comment: Kent, sure I can put `if/else` code around all the python code, but that was not my question. I would like to know if there is a possibility to return to the vim function where I have the command `return` inserted (please see above), without going to the bottom of my python code.